# Generate a dynamic, traditional URL (i.e. not an Action/Controller route) using @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create a dynamic  tag with a url containing JSON values that will be posted to an external payment gateway. Eventually I want something like this:

Pay This Amount

So I  figured I would do:

@Html.ActionLink("Pay This Amount", "https://xyz.com/PayNow?paymentData={'StoreID':'1964','Person':{'FirstName':'Joe','MiddleInitial':'A','LastName':'Smith'},'Item':{'1':{'Price':'250','Code':'TUITION'}}}")

But the resulting  tag makes the URL in Action/Controller format:

MyWebSite/MyController/https://xyz.com/PayNow?paymentData={'StoreID':'1964','Person':{'FirstName':'Joe','MiddleInitial':'A','LastName':'Smith'},'Item':{'1':{'Price':'250','Code':'TUITION'}}}

...and of course it fails.

I want just a traditional URL not a route. I don't see an overload for a simple  URL. Or is there another helper that I can use to create a non-MVC URL?

How do I do this? Thanks!

Thanks.

Comment: Is xyz.com a different host than your MVC site?

Comment: yes it is an external site.

Comment: Then the answer by @Dismissile should work.

Comment: Just tried it, it does not. For some reason even the URL generated in a <a> tag is interpreted as an MVC url i.e. it concatenates my website and Action/Controller. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please see my comment, @Dismissile's second suggestion worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Html.ActionLink is used to create an  tag to a controller/action in your site. If you just want to create a link to another site just use plain ole HTML:

```
<a href="https://xyz.com">Pay Now</a>
```

If you need to use properties from your model you can build the URL in code and then reference that in the tag:

```
@{
    string url = "https://xyz.com?id=" + Model.Id;
}

<a href="@url">Pay Now</a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://xyz.com?id=@Model.Id">Pay Now</a>
```

Comment: Hi, so @url does not work. It generates:

http://MyWebSite/MyController/MyAction/https://xyz.com...

Comment: Hmm...interesting, your second suggestion which I thought would be identical to the first did indeed work. i.e. 
<a href="https://xyz.com?id=@Model.Id">Pay Now</a>
I will see if I can somehow do this in code rather than in View. Thanks! marked as answered.